# R: read in a line from user input with newline character

Tags: r, user-input, readline

I am trying to use `readline()` for reading in a user input. My input has a newline character, which gets escaped, unfortunately.

```
> readline(prompt = "Tell me: ")
Tell me: first\nsecond
[1] "first\\nsecond"
```

How do I get

```
[1] "first\nsecond"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you simply want to remove the extra `\`? If so:

```r
x
#> [1] "first\\nsecond"

gsub("\\n", "\n", x, fixed = TRUE)
#> [1] "first\nsecond"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>